# Can an orderable field always be ordered in a way that extends a given subfield's ordering?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, ordered-fields

Let $F$ be an order*able* field, and let $\:\langle E,\hspace{-0.03 in}\leq \rangle \:$ be an [order*ed* subfield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field) of $F$.

Does it follow that $F$ can be made into an ordered field in a way that extends the ordering on $E\hspace{.02 in}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**.  Let $E = \mathbb{R}(t)$ with the ordering extending the unique one on $\mathbb{R}$ and in which $t > \alpha$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.  Let $F = \mathbb{R}(\sqrt{-t})$.  Clearly the ordering on $E$ does not extend to $F$.  But in fact $F \cong E$ as a field, so certainly $F$ can be ordered.

There is quite a rich theory of when orderings on fields extend from subfields.  A few results of this kind can be found on the chapter on ordered fields in [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/FieldTheory.pdf), but these don't even properly scratch the surface.  I recommend the book *Orderings, Valuations and Quadratic Forms* by T. Y. Lam as being a good place to start.  (Yes, there is more than a whole book's worth of material here.)